# onclick event is not working on ipad and tablet

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, tablet

onClick event not working on tablet,ipad? it is perfectly working on Pc browser but not working for touch events , i tried .binding(),.on()   and many thing but they are not giving 100% result.

How can I make it work on ipad , tablet??

```
<div id="id1" alt='div1' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img1.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">You've styled the div to have a set width of 100px. At a reasonable font size, that's too much text to fit in 100px. Without doing anything, </div>
<div id="id2" alt='div2' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img2.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 2</div>
```

Comment: you must try using `tap` instead of `click`. and if you're still stuck HTML's `onclick` attribute, god help u :P

Comment: post code here and you will get more answers

Comment: @passionateCoder  i have used onclick="" on div,because i read somewhere changing pointer to cursor and making onclick="" will make onclick work on ipad also

Comment: @simmisimmi what `onclick` is doing it is empty

Answer (score 4):

You need to use touchstart i get you a small example,

```
$('elementid').on('click touchstart', function() {
      console.log('1');
});
```

The touchstart event is fired when a touch point is placed on the touch surface.

Comment: 2020 and still working. but I used a function to identify the tablets and then I use just `touchstar` instead of `click tuchstart`. And keep using `click` for all other devices. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tap, swipe, taphold etc` events for the tablets,touch you can do this like

```
$('htmlelement').bind('click', ClickFunction ).bind('tap', ClickFunction );
```

Here are the list of jquery mobile events [events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html)

Also try to use the [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: ,Uncaught TypeError: Object .sliderImage has no method 'apply'   i get these error if i use .bind()

Answer (score 0):

You must have to bind the 'click' or 'tap' event for associated HTML control. You can bind like this

```
$('elementid').bind('click',function() {   alert('Click event triggered'); });
```

OR

```
$('elementid').bind('tap',function() {  alert('Tap event triggered'); });
```